# selectInput added using insertUI in shiny does not update reactive data

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I saw some previous questions that may circle around this issue, but I couldn't find a clear answer to that.

My problem is that an ui element added using `insertUI` that *depends on a reactive value* does not update.

In the example I gave below, if one adds the new `selectInput` using the button and then changes the gender selection, the choices are updated only in the first `selectInput`.

The question is: is there an "official" way to make this `selectInput` reactive? I can imagine some workarounds, but they are not ideal.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    req(input$genderSelection)
    starwars %>% 
      filter(gender == input$genderSelection)
  })

  output$characterSelection1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "char1",
      "Character 1",
      choices = data() %>% 
        .$name
    )
  })

  observeEvent(
      input$btn,
      {
          insertUI(
              selector = "#selection2",
              where = "beforeEnd",
              ui = selectInput(
                  "char2",
                  "Character 2",
                  choices = data() %>%
                      .$name
              )
          )
      }
  )
}
```

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(
    "genderSelection",
    "Gender",
    choices = c("male", "female")
  ),
  uiOutput("characterSelection1"),
  tags$div(
    id = "selection2",
    actionButton("btn", "Add selection")
  )
)
```

Comment: Oficially, "the UI generated with insertUI is not updatable as a whole: once it's created, it stays there". https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/insertUI.html

Comment: @DzimitryM. Thanks! I should have read the documentation more carefully...